# How to paginate data?

Tags: reactjs, api, pagination

How can I implement pagination to display 10 objects on a page? Here's my sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/rvo801wyp

Comment: check your link, https://codesandbox.io/s/yv5rq51qrz

Comment: I have made some changes, added show_list state and on click of page update only that page data into state and use arrow function to bind scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two things to do:

1. You need to either bind `handlePageChange` in the constructor or convert it to an arrow function
2. Add a slice to remove from `items` the data that's not going to be shown `.slice(this.state.activePage * this.state.itemsCountPerPage,(this.state.activePage + 1) * this.state.itemsCountPerPage)`

Take a look to my changes in the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/k58z3r9115

I've also added dynamically `itemsCountPerPage` to the state

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this objective,

- Pagination using API

  make API to handle some request param like

  ```
   {
      **per_page_limit**: <no of record on a single page>,
      **current_page**: <current page number>,
      ....other request param
   }
  ```
- Pagination on client end

  fetch all the records and create a pagination, for this get length of list and on bases of your requirement create pages,
       for eg. total record: 100
       per page limit: 10, so total pages will be 10
  now to show only data for page, use setState, and for data use

  list_data_to_display = list.slice(0, page*limit)

  this.setState({slow_list: list_data_to_display})

handlePageChange=(pageNumber)=> {}

Solution will be:

```
this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoading: false,
      activePage: 1,
      itemsCountPerPage: 1,
      totalItemsCount: 1,
      **show_list**: []
    };

show_list_data = () => {
    const show_list_data = this.state.items.slice(0, 10);
    this.setState({
      show_list: show_list_data
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://demo9197058.mockable.io/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState(
          {
            items: json,
            isLoading: true
          },
          this.show_list_data
        );
      });
  }
  handlePageChange = pageNumber => {
    console.log(`active page is ${pageNumber}`);

    const show_list_data = this.state.items.slice(
      (pageNumber - 1) * 10,
      pageNumber * 10
    );
    this.setState({
      show_list: show_list_data,
      activePage: pageNumber
    });
};

render() {
        var {  show_list, isLoading } = this.state;
        if (!isLoading) {
          return <div> loadding....</div>;
        } else {
          return (
            <div>
              <ul>
                {show_list.map(item => (

                ....
                ....
```